# how to connect two different table having similar foreign key?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am creating an accounting module with laravel and mysql. For that, I've master table called 'bills' which has some columns regarding invoice informations and `id` as primary key. Now I've two different tables called 'payments' having `bill_id` as foreign key and 'debitnotes' also having `bill_id` as foreign key.

Now I want to show payment history of particular bill which is paid. In order to that, I've to retrieve information from both payments table and debitotes table based on bill id at once! Now, my question is: How can I achieve this without writing multiple queries?

`bills` table has columns:

| id | bill_number | vendor_id | amount | amount_payable | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

`payments` table has columns:

| id | bill_id | transaction_number | amount | date | vendor_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

`debitnotes` table has columns:

| id | bill_id | debit_note_number | amount | vendor_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I want to show both payments and debitnotes of particular bills in single page. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Go through SQL joins concept and you could achieve this by joining tables with their reltaions.

Comment: Can you show some table schema please?

Comment: @Bohemian sir,i've updated my question with table details.please look into this. Please bear with it as i'm novice here,sorry for bad editing

Comment: Does `vendor_id` in the 3 tables contain the same value for a given bill? If not, please explain the meaning of each column.

Comment: @Bohemian yes sir,i forget to add vendor table where it has all details of vendors. The values are same in all of the three table.

Comment: @Bohemian a particular bill can have payment or debitnote or both! suppose if user have initiated half payment through online transaction and then generated debit note against remaining amount,then that bill will have both payment and debitnote. in that case,i want to display both payment and debit note in payment history section for that particular bill! i tried sql joins with zero success because i dont know how to display payment and debitnote separately. joins are joining both payment and debitnote table and displaying result in single row,but i want both to be displayed in separate row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `union`:

```
select
  'bill' source,
  id,
  bill_number number,
  vendor_id,
  amount,
  amount_payable,
  date
from bills
union all
  'payment',
  id,
  transaction_number,
  vendor_id,
  -amount amount, -- assuming payments cause the balance to lower
  null,
  date
from payments
union all
  'debitnote',
  id,
  debit_note_number,
  vendor_id,
  amount,
  null,
  date
from debitnotes
```

You should delete the `vendor_id` column from `payments` and `debitnotes` because it is redundant (or *denormalized*); it can be found by joining to the `bill` table.

Comment: it worked Sir! But what should i do to show different column for both tables? suppose payments can be made through online,cheque, or cash so it should show any of these mode,meanwhile debit note doesnot have any of this  so it should show debit note number instead! it showing cheque paid even in debit note column! how can i differentiate between these two column?

Comment: it can be done, but which column in `payments` indicates the payment method?

Comment: I've added new column in payments table called payment_mode to determine mode of payment...

Comment: Add a selected column to each query of the union, selecting `null` from the other tables, and name it `payment_type` in the first select. ie `select ..., null payment_type union ...`

Comment: thank you sir. i accepted your answer as final answer for this question. your suggestions have helped me a lot! Now Please bear my last quetion! :) how can i show different html table header for different table? like if the value is coming from 'payments' table then html table header should be like bill_number,vendor name,amount,payment mode,transection number etc and if it is from debitnotes table then html table header should be bill_number,vendor name,amount,debit note number etc.... the question is how can i differentiate between them without adding flags?

Comment: I've figured out previous problem by myself. Thank you for helping me thoroughly. Have a good day. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use join clause, and for payments and debitnotes, you can prepend the table name.

Here is an example from [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#inner-join-clause):

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
        ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
        ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
        ->get();
```